# Failing deposit transaction

Tags: solidity, polygon

The following [deposit transaction](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x8009aa71e48688b8075097fc1ff7e88faa5f60ec689b68e55ba912c520385ec8) on Mumbai test net is failing as opposed to [this transaction](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x3d664928276661b868d00518f966a54c3ebfddf8df98d53540f8c38ffe216da9) on Polygon main net which had succeeded years ago. There are no fundamental differences from code or parameters perspective that I could think of as possible reasons to explain this behaviour.

**Obs.**: In Mumbai a USDC test token was deployed and is linked to the contract we want to trigger the deposit function, and in Polygon main net, Circle's USDC is used.

Why is there this behaviour mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set allowance for the transfer back on deposit of your `yieldFarmingToken`. Your yieldFarming token currently [deployed here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xc31f68dc3af9855fbfb679eb6463d01f051122fd).

Without looking too much into the code, if you are doing this in a dApp UI, you need to let the spender make the call to allow an amount of the yieldFarming token to transfer.

Here's the relevant [increaseAllowance transaction](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x4f3762f5b3188f1a8a930d9ff0b581d1752b6d8ae8f269101088303c808114e4) on the mainnet that allowed the transaction you are referring to to go through https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x3d664928276661b868d00518f966a54c3ebfddf8df98d53540f8c38ffe216da9

Your [failing transaction](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x8009aa71e48688b8075097fc1ff7e88faa5f60ec689b68e55ba912c520385ec8) [doesn't have a prior increaseAllowance transaction](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xc31f68dc3af9855fbfb679eb6463d01f051122fd), so it's failing.

Relevant parts in the code:

- [Comment](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x843844bc6642650d65901d32111fac6773998904#code#L170)
- [Implementation](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x843844bc6642650d65901d32111fac6773998904#code#L317)

Comment: Despite the fact that I increased the allowance (https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xb7903cb94c90a5599d585593b083874de9a22cddcb568177ae8565528fa61acc) as per your answer, the deposit transaction (https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xdeff91190a0cf9918b79ddb1cdb358ed6fa10c9e15230f1d4e9569d54aca43a5) still failed.

Comment: I do not think there would be a need to increase allowance at the `yieldFarmingToken` as yieldFarming is minting tokens directly to the tokenTimeLock contract address upon USDC deposit.

Answer (score 0):

The account trying to make a deposit (0x150c1a134941cab797c1fca4f33ec1246076c578) have no LGBC tokens (farming token - 0xC31f68Dc3aF9855fbFB679EB6463d01f051122fD) to deposit. In fact totalSupply of this token is 0. You should mint some of these and send them to the account that tries to deposit[image]

Comment: The mint functionality happens upon USDC deposit as can be seen in the `YieldFarming` contract at deposit function: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x5225057dfba3e02d65f209f2c110537fe9bb177f#code#L2834

Comment: mint is called after super.deposit(depositor, amount), so at the time of the actual safeTransferFrom call (made in the parent's PaymentSplitter contract), no tokens had been minted yet. Also even if you switch it around (so depositor would have some tokens) you would still need to run approve transaction first, otherwise safeTramsferFrom would still fail because of no allowance being set